# Cannot run VCG Programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vcg

I am very new to VCG. I've cloned the devel branch of the Git repo and tried to run the `test/tetramesh` program in the`apps` directory to test out the install. When I load it up in VS Community 2015 and compile, it fails.

`Cannot open source file: No such file or directory`

After changing these paths to fit my file system, the program still won't compile. The files referenced in the aforementioned headers also have broken paths. There has to be better solution than manually editing all these files.

Some direction or a helpful link would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `test/tetramesh` I see that a lot of header files are not present. Also under project properties the folder locations are wrongly defined for `additional include directories`.

I wouldn't put too much effort in this test....